# Student name and mark class in python - undefined error while it is defined

Tags: python, class, undefined-reference, function-call

I honestly, did not want to paste this because it is a silly question but I tried and changed the code many times. The last few lines show the error of undefined object. Can you please help?

```
    class Studentsmarks(object):
      def __init__(self, name, testmark):
        self.name=name
        self.testmark=testmark
      
      def getmark(self): #function to return mark attribute from the class object
        return self.testmark
      
      def getname(self): #function to access the class object and return the name attribute from it
        return self.getname
    
      def __str__(self): 
        return self.name + ' : ' + str(self.getname()) +'  ::'+  str(self.getmark())
    
    # Define a function for building a Record 
    # which generates list of all the students 
      def studnetobject(rec,name, testmark):
        rec.append(Studentsmarks(name, testmark))
        return rec
    
      def main():
        studentlist=[]
        for each in range(0,1):
          name=input("Enter student name:")
          testmark=input("Enter student mark:")
          studentlist=studnetobject(rec, name, testmark) # << ----------------error undefined studentsobject
        printlist(studentlist)
    
      def printlist(studentlist):
      # Printing the list of student
        print("\n") 
        print("\nList of Students\n") 
        for i in range(studentlist.__str__()):     
          rec.display(studentlist[i]) # <<-------------------------------Undefined rec
```

Comment: your indents are a bit confusing.  Did you intend to have ```main()``` ```studnetobject``` and ```printlist``` within the ```Studentmarks``` class?

Comment: @ewong - yes, I tried both ways, when main, studentobject, and print list in and out the class - still have these errors

Comment: please post the full traceback

Answer (score 1):

I think there are several errors. I changed it considering your intention.

Here is the code I wrote...

```
class Studentsmarks(object):
    
    def __init__(self, name, testmark):
        self.name = name
        self.testmark = testmark

    def getmark(self): #function to return mark attribute from the class object
        return self.testmark

    def getname(self): #function to access the class object and return the name attribute from it
        return self.name

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name + ' : ' + self.getmark()
    
# Define a function for building a Record 
# which generates list of all the students 
def studnetobject(rec, name, testmark):
    rec.append(Studentsmarks(name, testmark))
    return rec

def main():
    studentlist=[]
    for i in range(0, 2): # 2 inputs (You can change here)
        name = raw_input("Enter student name:")
        testmark = raw_input("Enter student mark:")
        studentlist = studnetobject(studentlist, name, testmark)
    printlist(studentlist)

def printlist(studentlist):
    # Printing the list of student
    print("\n") 
    print("\nList of Students\n") 
    for i in range(len(studentlist)):
        print(studentlist[i])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

1. "raw_input" is more appropriate function. "raw_input" only returns string.
2. Changed "**str**" function. It prints name and mark.

You will also find other things. I hope this code helped you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @Schiz - I tried your code and it works..can you please explain what does the last line do? if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()     Just to learn

Comment: https://medium.com/python-features/understanding-if-name-main-in-python-a37a3d4ab0c3

Answer (score 0):

```
class Studentsmarks(object):
  def __init__(self, name, testmark):
    self.name=name
    self.testmark=testmark
  
  def getmark(self): 
    return self.testmark
  
  def getname(self): 
    return self.name

def studnetobject(rec, name, mark):
  rec.append([name,mark])
  return rec

def main():
  studentlist = []
  for each in range(0,2):
    name=input("Enter student name:")
    testmark=input("Enter student mark:")
    student_obj = Studentsmarks(name=name,testmark=testmark)
    rec=[]
    studentlist.append(studnetobject(rec, student_obj.getname(), student_obj.getmark())) 
  return studentlist

def printlist(studentlist):
  print("\nList of Students and marks\n") 
  for i in range(len(studentlist)):     
    print(studentlist[i])

studentlist = main()
printlist(studentlist)
```

Although this can be more simplified, to help you understand by comparing, i adapted your code.

[image]

Comment: Than you very much for your contribution - I tried it and it works. I think my mistake was when I did not pass the object attributes correctly. My code was: studentlist=studnetobject(rec, name, testmark) , while your correction was  studentlist.append(studnetobject(rec, student_obj.getname(), student_obj.getmark())) 
  return studentlist

Answer (score 0):

```
class Studentsmarks(object):
    def __init__(self, name, testmark):
        self.name=name
        self.testmark=testmark
    
    def getmark(self): #function to return mark attribute from the class object
        return self.testmark

    def getname(self): #function to access the class object and return the name attribute from it
        return self.name

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name + ' : ' + str(self.getname()) +'  ::'+  str(self.getmark())
    
    # Define a function for building a Record 
    # which generates list of all the students 
def studnetobject(name, testmark):
    return Studentsmarks(name, testmark)

def main():
    studentlist=[]
    for each in range(0,3):
        name=input("Enter student name:")
        testmark=input("Enter student mark:")
        studentlist.append(studnetobject( name, testmark)) # << ----------------error undefined studentsobject
    printlist(studentlist)

def printlist(studentlist):
# Printing the list of student
    print("\n") 
    print("\nList of Students\n") 
    print(*studentlist, sep='\n')
main()
```

im not know what output that you expect but i think it a good implementation in object.